# Get audio from docker container to host

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, dockerfile

I have a simple node.js app where I start playing a song from URL (using ffplay as a child process).

Locally everything works fine.

In Docker when I start playing, everything ok, no errors, but there is no sound on my laptop.

Is it possible to "expose" audio from docker to the host machine?

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --production
COPY src/ src/
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

I run this command

```
docker build . -t pig && docker run --rm --device /dev/snd --name pig pig
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [device](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container---device) flag to share host's sound with the container:

```
docker run ... --device /dev/snd image-name
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly not working. btw: I added my dockerfile